# C++:: Convert ASCII value to string in

Tags: c++, string, ascii

I am trying to convert an int that represents the ASCII value of a character to a single-character string.

I tried the following, and it does not work: 
`string s1=(char) 97;`

However, the conversion works only if I break the assignment apart like this:
`string s1; 
 s1=(char) 97;`

I am confused by this and can anyone explain the difference?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you just use itos()?

Comment: Even though it wasn't too hard to answer your question, next time you might want to be more precise than a mere "*it doesn't work*", because you basically provided **no** information whatsoever concerning the error you get. If you want help, you need to help us help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I tried the following, and it does not work: `string s1=(char) 97;`

That's because the [`std::string` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) doesn't have any overload that takes a single `char`. And also, copy is elided so the constructor is called directly, `operator =()` is never called (document yourself on **copy elision**).

> the conversion works only if I break the assignment apart like this: `string s1; s1=(char) 97;`

Now the copy is not elided any more, you are really calling [`std::string::operator =()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator=) which *does* have an overload accepting a single `char`.